# How do I restrict UIDocumentPicker from adding .sh executable files in iOS 14.0 swift?

Tags: swift, uidocumentpicker

Currently using `[.plainText, .spreadsheet, .html, .pdf, .xml, .presentation, .jpeg, .bmp, .gif, .png, .tiff, .content]` these UTTypes but still able to attach .sh type files , how do I restrict executable files by still supporting text and doc files.

Also UTType doesn't specify type for .doc, .docx files

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if you can restrict .sh file types considering that it is probably allowed when you accept plain text. Regarding the doc file type you can extend `UTTType` and implement your own `.doc` and `.docx` types:

```
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

extension UTType {

    static let doc: Self = .init(filenameExtension: "doc")!
    static let docx: Self = .init(filenameExtension: "docx")!

    static let xls: Self = .init(filenameExtension: "xls")!
    static let xlsx: Self = .init(filenameExtension: "xlsx")!

    static let ppt: Self = .init(filenameExtension: "ppt")!
    static let pptx: Self = .init(filenameExtension: "pptx")!

}
```

---

```
UTType.doc   // com.microsoft.word.doc
UTType.docx  // org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document

UTType.xls   // com.microsoft.excel.xls
UTType.xlsx  // org.openxmlformats.spreadsheetml.sheet

UTType.ppt   // com.microsoft.powerpoint.ppt
UTType.pptx  // org.openxmlformats.presentationml.presentation
```